# How do I get GNU grep to match exactly "H" and not things that just start with "H"?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file and I would like to do find the number of total number of occurrences of a passed in word, while supporting regex

```
grep -e "Hello*" filename | wc -w
```

But there a few bugs, I let's say I do something like

```
grep -e "H" filename | wc -w
```

It should only match EXACTLY H and not count things that start with H, the way grep does it right now.

Anyone know how?

Comment: For exact match of words, use `grep -w`.

Comment: Will that handle regex has well?

Comment: @Oujk Yes, `-w` is short for `--word-regexp` (see the grep manpage).

Comment: Do you want to match _lines that only contain `H` and nothing else_ or _lines that contain `H` as a single word but may contain also other strings_?

Comment: Not lines for words, all occurrences of the word within a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
grep '\bH\b'
```

e.g.:

```
kent$  echo "Hello
IamH
we need this H
and this H too"|grep '\bH\b'
we need this H
and this H too
```

Note that if you want to count only the matched words, you need to use `-o` option on `grep`. (thx fotanus)

**EDIT**

You can get all matched words by `grep -o`, in this case `-c` doesn't help, because it counts matched lines. you could pass `grep -o` to `wc -l`

for example:

```
kent$  echo "No Hfoo will be counted this line
this line has many: H H H H H H H (7)
H (8 starting)
foo bar (9 ending) H
H"|grep -o '\bH\b'|wc -l
10
```

**or simpler, single process solution with awk**:

```
awk '{s+=gsub(/\<H\>/,"")}END{print s}' file
```

same example:

```
kent$  echo "No Hfoo will be counted this line
this line has many: H H H H H H H (7)
H (8 starting)
foo bar (9 ending) H
H"|awk '{s+=gsub(/\<H\>/,"")}END{print s}'                                                                                                                                  
10
```

Comment: How would I then be about to sent this to wc, as I just want the occurrence count.

Comment: what is your input file format? one word per line? or like the example in my answer?

Comment: @Oujk Use `grep -c` for counting matching lines.

Comment: @Oujk note that counting matches is not equal counting words - use `-c` for counting matches, or `-w` with ` | wc -w` to count words.

Comment: Its a whole text document, so a line in the doc can have more than one occurrence which wc should count has more than once.

Comment: I'm trying the following 
grep '\b1995\b' ./file.txt | wc -c 
and it keeps returning a incorrect value than what it should.

Comment: @Oujk see EDIT. two solutions you could pick.

Comment: Thanks grep -o '\bH\b'|wc -l works well, but doesn't handle regex like grep -o '\bH*\b'|wc -l

Comment: @Oujk you have been asking for `H`, not `Hfoo`, `\bH*\b` matches words like `H HH HHH HHHHH` even empty string.

Comment: I see that's why, looks like I miss understood. I was thinking more along the lines of grep -e. Do you know how that would work?

Comment: @Oujk how **what** would work? you want to use `-e`, it's fine. read the man page how to use `-e` option. I cannot see how  `-e` option breaks the grep command in my answer. From my point of view, my answer provides the working solution for your problem. You could either edit your question, provide the information/example of your new problem, or better open a new question for your new requirement. Good Luck.