# GNU grep with regex support.

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I found the solution to [How do I get GNU grep to match exactly "H" and not things that just start with "H"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401848/how-do-i-get-gnu-grep-to-match-exactly-h-and-not-things-that-just-start-with) thanks to Kent using the following:

```
grep -o '\bH\b'|wc -l
```

But i need to support regex, so something like

```
grep -o '\bH*\b'|wc -l
```

Should match things like Hello, Hi, etc. Supporting all regex.

I think the -e option does this, but it doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `-e` just lets you specify one or more patterns to match against.  And while I understand what you're trying to accomplish, asking if you can have "GNU grep with regex support" is a little like asking if you can get a car that drives :)

Comment: '\bH\b'  **is** a valid regex, it just happens not to be using any wildcards or quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change

```
grep -o '\bH*\b'|wc -l
```

into

```
grep -oP '\bH.*?\b'|wc -l
```

your `H*` will match `H HH HHH HHH or empty string`

`\bH.*?\b` will match `H Hi Hallo Hello H_x_` means, `H` followed by non-word-boundary chars, till the next `\b`

if you just want to match letters, use `\bH[a-zA-Z]*\b`

**EDIT**

add example:

```
kent$  echo "H Hfoo Hbar xafHHH"|grep -Po '\bH.*?\b'
H
Hfoo
Hbar
```

Comment: Does that support all regex?

Comment: @Oujk you are confused by regex and glob. `ls foo*` lists all files starting with `foo` it is glob.  But if you say regex, `foo*` matches `foo, foooo,fooooooooo, foo` you could google for some regex tutorial for getting some basic regex knowledge.

Comment: Edit grep -oP '\bH.*?\b'|wc -l really just returns the line of the very first occurrence of \bH.*?\b and that only counts as one... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please paste some example data in your question

Comment: @Oujk I added an example. (without wc -l, but you see there are 3 lines)

Comment: I'm trying the following 

echo "Consulted he eagerness unfeeling deficient existence of. Calling nothing end fertile for venture way boy. Esteem spirit temper too say adieus who direct esteem. It esteems luckily mr or picture placing drawing no. Apartments frequently or motionless on reasonable projecting expression. Way mrs end gave tall walk fact bed." | grep -oP '\b.*t.*\b'|wc -l 

It is wrong.

Comment: you want -E `echo blah | grep -Eo '\b.*t.*\b'|wc -l`

Comment: of course it is wrong did u even read my answer? You used a completely different regex! It matches all text containing t. Not beginning with t. Also greedy match. So u got one single line. Again read some regex tutorial. It is very basic problem.